# Eine Alternative zu "schwerfallen"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> Es fällt mir schwer, deutsche Redewendungen zu verstehen.

```
  I am having difficulties comprehending German idioms.
```

Was sind Alternativen zum Verb "schwerfallen"?

Comment: There are 2 little mistakes in your example. The correct sentence would be *"Es fällt mir schwer, die deutschen Redewendungen zu verstehen"*.

Comment: check the synonyms section of the [article on duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schwerfallen)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

to comprehend = verstehen

"Es fällt mir schwer, **deutsche Redewendungen** zu verstehen." (all German idioms)

"Es fällt mir schwer, **diese deutsche Redewendung** zu verstehen." (only this one)

Alternativen zu 
something is difficult for someone. = etwas fällt jemandem schwer
Infinitiv: schwerfallen

"Deutsche Redewendungen bereiten mir Schwierigkeiten."

Umkehrung (It is not easy for me to …)
"Es fällt mir nicht leicht, deutsche Redewendungen zu verstehen."

Umgangssprachlich:
"Deutsche Redewendungen fallen mir schwer."

Answer (score 3):

> "Ich finde es herausfordernd, deutsche Redewendungen zu verstehen."

oder die ursprüngliche Version nur leicht geändert

> "Es fällt mir nicht leicht, deutsche Redewendungen zu verstehen."